# Relatório com date_trunc incluindo valores zerados

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou fazendo uma consulta no postgres, porém ela só trás os resultados aonde a instância de fiscalizações não está zerada, precisava que essa consulta trouxesse todos os resultados das 8 as 18, inclusive os zerados:

**COMO TRAZ:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**COMO QUERIA QUE TROUXESSE:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**QUERY:**

```
select (
          date_trunc('hour', data)

           )                 intervalo_data,
       count(id) fiscalizacoes
from fiscalizacoes
where data >= '2019-06-21 08:00:0.000000'
  and data <= '2019-06-21 18:00:00.000000'
group by intervalo_data
order by intervalo_data;
```

Comment: está usando `date_trunc` no select mas está agrupando com a data normal? não parece que vai funcionar como espera, tem que deixar o group by igual ao select

Comment: O agrupamento está funcionando, eu executei e devolveu  o que eu esperava, até porque tenho que trazer o número de fiscalizações por intervalo de 1 hora, das 8 as 18.

Comment: não é que não esteja funcionando, mas ele agrupa pela data inteira sem truncar horas. Existem todas essas horas que não está retornando, por exemplo 11:00:00?

Comment: agrupei pelo date_trunc('hour', data) e continua com o mesmo resultado, não está ignorando os resultados

Comment: mas se não agrupar, existe registro nas horas que estão faltando?

Comment: não existe, é esta a minha pergunta, se tem como eu retornar 0 para as horas que não possuem instância.

Comment: ah agora entendi :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível gerar as datas todas usando a função [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

`generate_series(timestamp '2019-06-21 00:00:0.00000', '2019-06-21 23:00:0.00000', '1 hour')`

Basicamente gera uma série de datas(`timestamp`, mas poderia ser `int`, e gerar um intervalo de números inteiros por exemplo), tem o início e fim, e ao final o intervalo desejado, que é em horas (cada 1 hora).

A partir daí, basta fazer um `LEFT JOIN` com a tabela (`LEFT` pois queremos preservar as datas que não houverem na tabela "fiscalizacoes") e agrupar normalmente:

```
SELECT  date_trunc('hour', datas.data) intervalo_data,
 count(f.id) fiscalizacoes
  FROM (
       SELECT day::timestamp as data
         FROM generate_series(timestamp '2019-06-21 00:00:0.00000', '2019-06-21 23:00:0.00000', '1 hour') day
       ) datas
LEFT JOIN fiscalizacoes f ON f.data = datas.data
GROUP BY intervalo_data
ORDER BY intervalo_data;
```

Coloquei um exemplo funcionando aqui: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b0d8d/31)

Comment: valeu muito obrigado, funcionou.

Comment: eu tb agradeço, eu tinha visto essa função para números inteiros e não sabia se gerava datas tb, ai pesquisei e montei essa resposta, acabei aprendendo algo novo :)