# Como retornar horário no MySQL mesmo não possuindo registro naquele horário

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso agrupar dados num intervalo de 15 minutos, me dando o numero total de veículos, em determinado intervalo de datas.
O que consegui até então, foi essa *query*:

```
SELECT Date_format(data_hora, "%y-%m-%d") AS dataFormat, 
       Date_format(( Sec_to_time(Time_to_sec(data_hora) - 
                                 Time_to_sec(data_hora)%( 15 * 
                                 60 )) ), "%h:%i") AS 
       intervals, 
       eq_id, 
       Sum(online_status), 
       data_hora 
FROM   tb_status 
WHERE  (data_hora BETWEEN '2019-08-15 16:00:00' AND '2019-08-16 17:00:00') 
GROUP  BY dataformat, 
          intervals, 
          eq_id 
ORDER  BY 3,2,1;
```

Essa *query* retorna uma boa parte do que preciso, porém, ela não retorna horários em que não possuem dados, por exemplo:

```
2019-08-15 16:15:00 ...
2019-08-15 16:30:00 ...
2019-08-15 16:45:00 ...
2019-08-15 17:00:00 ...
2019-08-15 17:30:00 ...      <------ Pulou um intervalo
2019-08-15 16:45:00 ...
```

Comment: Veja no manual as Common Table Expressions com a cláusula WITH (com o intervalo de tempo desejado) e utilize o resultado em um LEFT OUTER JOIN com sua tabela.

Comment: Vou verificar! Obrigado pelo comentário, agora tenho por onde começar novamente!

Comment: veja essa outra pergunta, deve ajudar é um caso bem parecido: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/398850/57220

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo! vou me basear nessa pergunta